# Gijgo Grid with MVC Uncaught TypeError

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, grid

I am trying to use the Gijgo jQuery Grid in an ASP.Net MVC 5 application and am hitting a problem when the grid is rendered. The problem is in the method gj.widget.prototype.getHTMLConfig in the line:

```
var result = this.data(),
attrs = this[0].attributes;
```

The error is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined".

My html is this, it's in a partial view:

```
<table id="grid" data-source='@Url.Action("RecentIssues", "Issue")' data-url='@Url.Action("Issue", "Issue")')></table>
```

My initialisation script for the grid is:

```
var grid = $('#grid').grid({
        columns: [
            { field: 'Id', hidden: true, cssClass: 'grid-text' },
            { field: 'Type', width: 70, sortable: true, cssClass: 'grid-text' },
            { field: 'Created', width: 70, sortable: true, type: 'date', format: 'dd/mm/yyyy', cssClass: 'grid-text' },
            { field: 'Title', width: 600, sortable: true, cssClass: 'grid-text' },
            { field: 'Status', width: 70, sortable: true, cssClass: 'grid-text' },
            { field: 'Priority', width: 70, sortable: true, cssClass: 'grid-text' },
            { field: 'Severity', width: 70, sortable: true, cssClass: 'grid-text' },
            { field: 'Product', width: 150, sortable: true, cssClass: 'grid-text' }
        ]
    });
```

The grid does actually display but because I am using ajax to populate the "content" part of my page, I need to manually initialise the grid, this is where the problem happens in that the script which is manually initialising things gets terminated because of the error in the Grid.

jQuery version 2.2.4

Bootstrap version 3.3.7

GijGo Grid V1.0.0

Apart from this problem which is holding me back, the Gijgo Grid appears to be excellent and just what I am looking for.

Any assistance is very much appreciated.

John

Answer (score 0):

Probably the $('#grid') selector can't find the html tag. You can try with the latest version of the grid, where you are going to get more user friendly error if you face this issue.

Answer (score 0):

can you create your grid this way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var grid = $('#grid').grid({
                dataKey: "Id",
                dataSource: '@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("RecentIssues", "Issue"))',
                columns: [
                    { field: 'Id', hidden: true, cssClass: 'grid-text' },
                    { field: 'Type', width: 70, sortable: true, cssClass: 'grid-text' },
                    { field: 'Created', width: 70, sortable: true, type: 'date', format: 'dd/mm/yyyy', cssClass: 'grid-text' },
                    { field: 'Title', width: 600, sortable: true, cssClass: 'grid-text' },
                    { field: 'Status', width: 70, sortable: true, cssClass: 'grid-text' },
                    { field: 'Priority', width: 70, sortable: true, cssClass: 'grid-text' },
                    { field: 'Severity', width: 70, sortable: true, cssClass: 'grid-text' },
                    { field: 'Product', width: 150, sortable: true, cssClass: 'grid-text' }
                ]
            });
        });
```

Next thing i to make sure that your web api/MVC action call returns JSON:

```
public JsonResult GetContractItems(int contractFK)
{
    //Dummy method GetIssues
    List<Issue> issues = contractManager.GetIssues(Issue);
    var issuesList = from o in issues
    select new
        {
            Id = o.Id,
            Type = o.Type,
            Created = o.Created,
            Title = o.Title,
            Status = o.Status,
            Priority = o.Priority,
            Severity = o.Severity,
            Product = o.Product
        };
    return Json(new { status = "success", records = issuesList.ToList() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond but this question is 3 years old and I think I used an alternative grid in the end.